# What am I doing wrong when updating my user's credits and storing it to userDefaults?

Tags: swift

My code below has a button, pressing which should increase the number of credits my user has by 3. I have used get/set property observers for my variable to be saved to userDefaults. While the credits label reflects the change (increases by 3), the number isn't saved to userDefaults, and consequently resets back to the base number when I kill and restart the app.

```
var livesLeft: Int {
    get {
        return UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "livesLeftSaved")
    }
    set {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: "livesLeftSaved")
    }
}

lazy var livesLeftLabel: UILabel = {
   let label = UILabel()
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    livesLeft = 0
    label.text = String(livesLeft)
    label.font = UIFont(name: "GillSans-BoldItalic", size: 25)
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.numberOfLines = 2
    return label
}()

  let addLivesButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.setImage(UIImage(named: "icon"), for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pressedButton), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
}()

@objc func pressedButton() {
    livesLeft += 3
    //I think the mistake I'm making is in the next line of code//
    livesLeftLabel.text = String(livesLeft)
}
```

While the label gets updated from 0 to 3 on pressing the button, it fails to save the increased number to userDefaults and consequently the user loses his credits once I kill the app.

I know I'm missing out on something very trivial here, I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong

Comment: You set `livesLeft` to `0` in your lazy initializer for `livesLeftLabel`

Comment: @NoodleOfDeath did that intentionally; I was under the wrong impression that my property observers will take care of that for me, I realise that made no sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is here:

```
lazy var livesLeftLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    livesLeft = 0 *** HERE ***
```

You are resetting the livesLeft value when you load the label.

Just change this line to

```
livesLeftLabel.text = String(livesLeft)
```